# Recursion Error: maximum recursion depth exceeded - API calls

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to make an API call to fetch the stock market data for each ticker symbol. My code iterates over each ticker symbol and the value is passed to the Quandl API call.

```
tickrs = ['MMM', 'ABT', 'ABBV', 'ACN', 'ATVI', 'AYI', 'ADBE', 'AMD', 'AAP', 'AES']

d = {}
chunk_size = 50
for i in range(0,len(tickrs),chunk_size):
    chunk = tickrs[i:i+chunk_size]
    for c in chunk:
        #API call to fetch data
        d[c] = qd.get_table('WIKI/PRICES', qopts = {'columns': ['ticker', 'date', 'close']}, ticker=c, date = { 'gte': '2016-11-01', 'lte': '2017-11-01' }, paginate=True)
```

I am not sure why it throws a maximum recursion error. I don't see where it exceeds recursion. I have tried changing recursion limit to max which didn't work.

Traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RecursionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-81-eea8a436b267> in <module>()
         5     for c in chunk:
         6         #API call to fetch data
---->    7         d[c] = qd.get_table('WIKI/PRICES', qopts = {'columns': 
         ['ticker', 'date', 'close']}, ticker=c, date = { 'gte': '2016-11-01', 
          'lte': '2017-11-01' }, paginate=True)
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not just iterating through `tickrs` directly but instead have broken it up into chunks?

Comment: @eugenhu It was a check against recursion to see if it behaves the same way. I figured, perhaps, slicing the tickrs by chunks may help fix the recursion issue.

Comment: It might help others to spot your issue better if you can simplify your sample code to the minimum needed to replicate your error.

Comment: I added a sample of `tickrs` that I am passing to the function. In order to replicate, you'd need to setup quandl API. but the code should give you a general gist of what I am trying to accomplish.